# How select where left chars in 2 columns equal all cases of 2 columns in 2nd table that equal some value for another column in 2nd table

Tags: mysql

key_table

```
key1    key2    ansr      
36  7600    IU-3  
36  9500    OPD  
01  0100    T3 R  
01  0104    T3 L  
01  3900    T4 R  
03  0202    T3 R
```

base_table

```
base1   base2  
367123  7600jjkl  
01juty  0202qqrr  
018723  3900juyt  
03ppot  0202qrt  
3674t5  9500qqpp  
01y756  0100hutt
```

I want to be able to return all rows from base_table where the first 2 chars of base1 and the first 4 chars of base2 equal are together in a row with some answer in key_table.

Thus, a search to match OPD as ansr in key_table would return only the base_table row:

```
base1   base2  
3674t5  9500qqpp
```

While a search to match T3 R  as ansr in key_table would return the base_table rows:

```
base1   base2  
01y756  0100hutt  
03ppot  0202qrt
```

I tried the following, grimacing as I submitted, without success:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `base_table`
 WHERE left(`base1`,2) = key1 
   and left(`base2`,4) = key2 in (SELECT `key1`,`key2` FROM `key_table` WHERE `ansr` = 'R-1')
```

I think I can accomplish this with an inner join, but am wondering if there is a way to do this more like my futile attempt above.

Comment: Grimacing is good. But problems like this generally stem from poor design

Comment: In this case, both tables are direct imports of datafeeds, thus we feel somewhat stuck with the structure ,at least at the moment of import. I suppose we could create a new table or tables that might be more efficient, but the solution provided by @java_guy did the trick and it allows us to import feeds "as is" and forget. In any case, I'm interested in any more detailed thoughts you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM base_table WHERE
CONCAT(left(base1,2), left(base2,4))
in (SELECT CONCAT(key1, key2) FROM key_table WHERE ansr = 'OPD')
```

Output is:

```
3674t5 9500qqpp
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!